# Firebase Firestore Maximum Write Rate Limit For a Single Document For Batch Writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As mentioned in [Firestore usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits), maximum sustained write rate to a document is 1 per second. Is it also valid for [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) writes, or does it already respect this limit?

I know it is a soft limit, but according to [Best practices for Cloud firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates):
*"Pay special attention to the 1 write per second limit for documents and the limit of 1,000,000 concurrent connections per database. These are soft limits that Cloud Firestore does not stop you from exceeding. However, going over these limits might affect performance, depending on your total read and write rates."*

For example, is the following code block problematic, or batch writes handle it accordingly?

```
const testRef = firestore.collection("testCollection").doc("testDoc");
const testRef2 = firestore.collection("testCollection").doc("testDoc2");

const batch = db.batch();

batch.update(testRef, {
  test1: "test1",
});

batch.update(testRef, {
  test22: "test22",
});

batch.update(testRef, {
  test33: "test33",
});

batch.update(testRef2, {
  test444: "test444",
});

batch.update(testRef2, {
  test5555: "test5555",
});

await batch.commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: the soft limit of 1 write per document per second has been removed from the documentation. The actual limit depends on the workload of your app as a whole, so measure and monitor the performance under load for the best insights.

Original answer below

---

As the documentation says, the 1 write to a document per second is not a hard limit that is enforced. It's instead merely the physical limit of how frequently the data in the document (and the indexes) can be updated.

If you perform sustained writes more frequently than the limit, you may see delays in how long it takes to commit a write.

There is no difference here batched writes. They're merely a bunch of writes that happen in a single context, but it doesn't affect this limit in any meaningful way.

That said, a single batch like you have in your code is not going to cause problems either way.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not state that there is a 1 write to a document per second limit. It was updated. See: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document